# Non-nullable instance field '_description' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

"Non-nullable instance field '_description' must be initialized."

A partir da versão 2.12.0, o Flutter sempre exibe mensagens como esta, como resolver esse problema sem baixar a versão?

Pesquisando, vi que poderia colocar o "?" próximo ao tipo:

String? _Descrição;

Mas não entendi bem o que isso faz e ao mesmo tempo gera outros erros no meu projeto

De forma resumida, como declarar objetos nulo no Dart sem ser obrigado a passar valor.

Comment: Quando você coloca o `?`, você está dizendo que esse objeto pode ser nulo, portanto, para acessá-lo em outra parte do código, você precisa verificar se aquele objeto é nulo ou não. Certamente, esses outros erros que você está vendo seja por isso, vc está tentando acessar um objeto que pode ser nulo sem qualquer verificação. Você pode resolver rapidamente colocando `!` na frente do objeto, por exemplo: `print(_Descricao!.toLowerCase())`... se _Descricao for nulo, vai dar erro. Pra n dar erro, vc pode usar o `??`, assim: `print(_Descricao ?? 'descricao nula!')`

Comment: Quanto ao erro do título, `_description` **não** está marcada como nula, ou seja, você **tem** que inicializá-la, pois ela nunca será nula. Não deveriam ter fechado sua pergunta... stack br fecha pergunta a rodo e.e.